# CodeIgniter function for returning special dropdown

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create a function in my model that does something a bit different and need a bit of help.

I have a database table with names, description, ids etc etc .... there is only one of each name, but i want to return 3 entries for every 1 name, prefixed with a number on it.

So, for example, if i have 2 entries in my database with the names 'joe' and 'bob' .... i want my dropdown box to look like the following

```
<select>
<option value="joe1">joe1 - description</value>
<option value="joe2">joe2 - description</value>
<option value="joe3">joe3 - description</value>
<option value="bob1">bob1 - description</value>
<option value="bob2">bob2 - description</value>
<option value="bob3">bob3 - description</value>
```

and so on for additional entries in the DB.

i understand how to do a normal dropdown box, but not one like this.

Any help would be grand :)

Comment: can you list your model code and view code for seeing this option?

Comment: I dont have any model code .... thats what im trying to figure out how to do

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function get_users()
{
    $this->db->select("id,name,desc");
    $this->db->from("table_name");

    $q = $this->db->get();

    $rows = $q->row_array();
}
```

In controller method:

```
$data = array();
$data['users'] = $this->model_name->get_users();

$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```

In view:

```
<?php
echo "<SELECT>";

foreach($users as $user)
{
    for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
    {
            $id = $user['id'].$i;
            echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.' - '.$user['desc'].'</option>';
    }
}

echo "</SELECT>";
?>
```

Comment: Should i put that in the model? ... or straight into the view?

Comment: I edited the answer and split up the code into Model, View and Controller sections.

Comment: Im now getting - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() .. Should there be a return in the model somewhere?

Comment: ya, sorry, last line should be return $rows;

Comment: Hmmm ... now thats not right .... Now its only echoing the first letter of the first entry 6 times :S

Comment: Can you paste the specific code you're using and the output HTML?